# Magento: Unable to add new transaction email template due to missing Mage/Email/Helper/Data.php

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm trying to add a new email template via adminhtml -> system -> transactional email -> new template.

However, when I go to  that page, the drop down list for the default template has no option in it and there is nothing else on that page.

I checked on /var/log/system.log and the found the following lines:

- Warning: include(Mage/Email/Helper/Data.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream:
  No such file or directory  in
  /home/jille/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
- Warning: include() [function.include]:
  Failed opening 'Mage/Email/Helper/Data.php' for inclusion
  (include_path='/home/jille/public_html/app/code/local:/home/jille/public_html/app/code/community:/home/jille/public_html/app/code/core:/home/jille/public_html/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')
  in /home/jille/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93

I went into the source and could not find any reference to this file. Any idea on how to fix this issue?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If helper is used or in translate xml node you refer to module then magento will search for module/Helper/Data.php file.

You just create a file data.php
 class Mage_Modulename_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}

This will fix your error.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I'll try this tomorrow and we'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: I just tested it. The problem solved. Thank you very much for sharing your knowledge.